# Changing size of glui window

Tags: glut, glui

Can anyone tell me if there is any function for changing size of glui window? Also do anyone have any idea about how to add scroll bars to glut window?
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

did you try glutReshapeWindow?

```
void glutReshapeWindow(int width, int height);
```

> glutReshapeWindow requests a change in the size of the current window. The width and height parameters are size extents in pixels. The width and height must be positive values.

Comment: i am asking about GLUI window. GLUT and GLUI windows are different

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify the version you are using, but v2.2 comes with some examples. If you check **example5.cpp** and **example3.cpp**, you'll notice that a GLUI window is created on top of a GLUT window (see the code below):

```
int main_window = glutCreateWindow( "GLUI Example" ); // Creating GLUT window

// Setting up callbacks
glutDisplayFunc( myGlutDisplay );
GLUI_Master.set_glutReshapeFunc( myGlutReshape );  // Humm, this could be it!
GLUI_Master.set_glutKeyboardFunc( myGlutKeyboard );
GLUI_Master.set_glutSpecialFunc( NULL );
GLUI_Master.set_glutMouseFunc( myGlutMouse );

// Blah Blah to create objects and make it fancy

GLUI* glui = GLUI_Master.create_glui( "GLUI", 0, 400, 500 ); // Create GLUI window
glui->set_main_gfx_window( main_window );  // Associate it with GLUT
```

So it seems you have 2 options: **the first**, execute the callback `myGlutReshape()` directly to see if it resizes the window (specified below):

```
void myGlutReshape( int x, int y )
{
  int tx, ty, tw, th;
  GLUI_Master.get_viewport_area( &tx, &ty, &tw, &th );
  glViewport( tx, ty, tw, th );

  xy_aspect = (float)tw / (float)th;

  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

or (**the second**), which is calling `glutReshapeWindow()` to change the window dimensions (probably followed by *glutPostRedisplay()*) .

```
glutReshapeWindow( 800, 600);
glutPostRedisplay(); // This call may or may not be necessary
```

Notice that `glutReshapeWindow()` is also executed by the callback, so this cold be the answer after all.